# Get populated data map after calling Form.fill method in Play 2.5

Tags: data-binding, playframework, playframework-2.0

In Play we can populate a Form object with the fill method :

```
Form<MyClass> myForm = formFactory.form(MyClass.class).fill(new MyClass("some", "data"));
```

However when we call the method data() on the form object, It will return an empty set, which is not what I was expecting. How could we find a way to retrieve a Map<> of parsed bounded data ?

```
myForm.data() // {} empty !
```

Only way I see for now is to get data one by one calling the method

```
myForm.field("fieldA").value()
```

I want to achieve this in order to beneficiate from data binding that I have defined in my custom Formatter, like for Date formats.

Comment: In scala at least, myForm.data correctly returns the whole map, and myForm.data() is an invalid expression. I would expect myForm.data("some") to return "data", or myForm.data.keys to return the list of form field names...